# With or without "that"/"which"

Tags: optional-that

I'm trying to understand something about the following sentence:

*The graph highlights data about how much **gas was** produced in Russia between 2003 and 2008.*

Would it be correct to include "that" or "which" between "gas was"?

If you asked the question:

*How much gas was produced in Russia between 2003 and 2008?*

Then you could answer: *The graph highlights data about* (***followed by the question itself***), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not be correct.

The problem arises because of the modifiers **how much** before gas.

Thus you can say:

> The graph highlights data about the gas **that** was produced in Russia....

and

> The graph highlights data about the gas, **which/that** was produced from Siberian coal, in Russia between....

But, if you ask the question:

> How much gas was produced in Russia .....

The answer is:

> The graph indicates how much gas was produced in Russia....

Equally you can say:

> The graph indicates the gas **that** was produced in Russia....

But the conjunction **that** doesn't fit after **how much**

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-that/

Answer (score 2):

> *The graph highlights data about* [*how much gas was produced in Russia*
>   *between 2003 and 2008*].

No: you can't do that.

The bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of the preposition "about". The meaning is:

*"The graph highlights data about the answer to the question 'How much gas was produced* *in Russia between 2003 and 2008?'"*